# getting rows from a MySQL database associated with tags through a link table

Tags: mysql, search, tags

I have three MySQL tables, one with data, one with tags and one with associations between those two, which seems to be common practice when storing tags. The tables look like this:

```
links:
+----+------------+------------+
| id | url        | added      |
+----+------------+------------+
| 2  | google.com | 2012-12-14 |
| 3  | cnn.com    | 2001-02-13 |
+----+------------+------------+

tags:    
+----+--------+
| id | tag    |
+----+--------+
| 1  | search |
| 2  | news   |
+----+--------+


taglink:
+----+--------+-------+
| id | linkid | tagid |
+----+--------+-------+
| 1  | 2      | 1     |
| 2  | 3      | 1     |
| 3  | 3      | 2     |
+----+--------+-------+
```

What I want to receive is the following table:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| id | url        | added      | tagids | tags        |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| 2  | google.com | 2012-12-14 | 1      | search      |
| 3  | cnn.com    | 2001-02-13 | 1,2    | search,news |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
```

To do so I had this query:

```
select 
   links.*,
   group_concat(taglink.id) as tagids,
   group_concat(tags.tag) as tags
from links
   join taglink on taglink.linkid=links.id
   join tags on tags.id=taglink.tagid
```

but this gives me a single row with every tag used, like so:

```
+----+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| id | url        | addad      | tagids | tags        |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
| 2  | google.com | 2012-12-14 | 1,2    | search,news |
+----+------------+------------+--------+-------------+
```

Everything seems to be grouped, which is not what I was looking for. Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: Please consider accepting the answers to some of the questions you've asked.  Click on the green check box by the best answer.

Comment: I do that for every answer that answer my question... I do a lot of searching before I write a question here... I'm doing my best to help this great community every way I can ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` with your `group_concat` functions as follows, or they'll behave unpredictably.  Try this.

```
    select links.id, links.url, links.added,
           group_concat(tags.id ORDER BY tags.id) as tagids,
           group_concat(tags.tag ORDER BY tags.id) as tags
      from links
      join taglink on taglink.linkid=links.id
      join tags on tags.id=taglink.tagid
  group by links.id, links.url, links.added
  order by links.id
```

Note that I've added some `ORDER BY` items to make the order of things predictable.

Go fiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b3b9/5/0

Comment: If you find yourself using `SELECT *` in a query with aggregate functions like `MAX()` or `GROUP_CONCAT()` you're probably doing something wrong.  You're definitely doing something sloppy and non-portable.

Comment: That indeed gives the desired result for the given table. I ran into another problem, added a link without tags which should come back in the results as well, but with no tags. I changed the "join" to "left join" and that took care of that problem! (fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b772/2/0)